# LeafletJS Measurement of distance in deepzoom tilelayer

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have been trying to understand how LeafletJS determines distances between two points in a layer. I am trying to implement the [custom scale plugin](https://github.com/jtreml/leaflet.customscale), (and have done so successfully) on a static tiled image using the [leaflet deepzoom tilelayer plugin](https://github.com/alfarisi/leaflet-deepzoom).

**Added Information**

Using CRS.Simple, the image zoom is adjusted by powers of 2 by the looks of it:

CRS.Simple seems to operate in powers of 2:

`o.CRS.Simple=o.extend({},o.CRS,{projection:o.Projection.LonLat,transformation:new o.Transformation(1,0,-1,0),scale:function(t){return Math.pow(2,t)}})`

Constants that I know:

1. DPI
2. tile size (256 x 256 pixels)
3. map size in pixels (bounds of the image)
4. leaflet zoom level
5. size of image in the real world

What do I change in Leaflet to allow me to make accurate scale bars?

Answer (score 1):

If tiles are always 256x256 pixels, with one tile covering the planet at zoom level 0, increasing by powers of 4 at every zoom level, then roughly calculating distance per pixel at any zoom level is relatively straightforward (given the [inherent errors of distance measurement in EPSG:3857](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/))

If your image has been correctly georeferenced, split into tiles that are 256x256 pixels to match Leaflet's global {x}{y}{z} referencing system, and then displayed using Leaflet, then the custom scale plugin should work... But it sounds like you are using Leaflet as a continuous zoom viewer, without regard to where your tiles fit on earth in {x}{y}{z} space, and therefore the scale bar and the pixel distance per zoom table you referenced will not apply.

Comment: Fair enough. Reading that article makes it seem that using EPSG for precise measurements is not all that helpful anyways (nor what I want) Is there a way to make more precise measurements with L.CRS.Simple? 

CRS.Simple seems to operate in powers of 2 'o.CRS.Simple=o.extend({},o.CRS,{projection:o.Projection.LonLat,transformation:new o.Transformation(1,0,-1,0),scale:function(t){return Math.pow(2,t)}})'

Comment: is your image something like a 'map', or are you just zooming an arbitrary image, like the hubble example, and trying to do do measurements on that? If its a map, maybe use gdal2tiles, which will cut tiles to fit web mercator projection. Then built in leaflet scale tools will work. As far as I can tell, Leaflet scale is doing some tranformation, in the [example](http://jtreml.github.io/leaflet.customscale/example.customscale.html), move the map north or south and you can see the scale adjust. A look at the code itself should give more insight into what it's doing

Comment: sorry, but not familiar enough with L.CRS.simple to answer your specific question

Comment: I'll take a look at the example again. The problem I'm running into is its not a map, so a lot of the normal tools aren't specifically catered to my task. I suspect the way of doing it is basically the same; it just won't use EPSG stuff.

Comment: So, I'm not having much luck. If I change my tileset source from deepzoom to a referenced {x}{y}{z} format using a TMS layer, will that allow proper measurement of the distances?